# Should there be Groups rather than Top-Down listing

Tags: discussion

I find that the listings is just top-down, so when several question may be getting posted as is the case most of the time, your question might lose visibility and may not seek any responses.

While Superuser site deploys good filters and tagging mechanism, a logical grouping may help users selectively browse their areas of interest and more questions may get attended.
Thanks.

Comment: Grouping how? If you were interested in Windows XP, you'd have http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-xp as your page

Comment: You mean to group the tags into general areas of interest like Windows, Unix, Apple, Networking, Office, Web?  There would be some value in that, but I think the tags serve that purpose pretty well even though they are ungrouped now.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you'd like to see?  I'm totally missing the concept.

Comment: Yes, logical grouping of tags like Hardware, Software & Apps, Operating Systems, Networking, Embedded Systems etc So ongoing posts are spread over interested users / reviewers, rather than just going top-down. Just a suggestion though. Thanks.

Comment: It is a good idea , and will be an even better idea when there is 1500 questions a day, but there is not, and there could be, but there won't :-)  Sub-grouping of topics instead of One more stack exchange site set up to seperate, because it would be more convinient to participate on one site , than to hop from site to site for the same thing.  It is not likely to be observed that way, and the tags are a partial way to solution it, after all partial solutions are the best kind.